# How to pull changes to SQLite database file for Flask web app from GitHub repository

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, github, flask

I have a repository for a Flask web application, hosted on Heroku and attached to a GitHub repository, that allows users to enter information which is then inserted into a SQLite database, and displayed on the website. I want to pull the changes to the repository, i.e. the database with the user submitted information, so I can make changes without wiping clear the database. However, when I pull from GitHub, the database has no changes and remains empty, even though users have submitted information. How can I download the edited database file?

Comment: As Code Yard says below, you need to use a client-server database on Heroku. SQLite is a file-based database, and is therefore [unsuitable for use on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3). [Heroku's own Postgres service](https://www.heroku.com/postgres) is a reasonable choice, but there [are others](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it doesn't work like that. When you change a file in heroku, it doesn't reflect the same in GitHub or git repo.
Heroku uses a dyno system meaning that when a restart happens then the files are reloaded. Nothing is saved. 
You would need to use Heroku Postgres for your database or something similar