# Can I disable the automatic restarting of Heroku dynos?

Tags: heroku

Is there a way to disable Heroku's automatic restarting of dynos, or at least schedule when they are to restart?

Comment: It's not possible to disable the automatic restarting of free apps. It is also not possible to schedule them as far as I know. You can manually reset the time by turning the dyno off and on. It might be possible for you to implement a timer in your program and intentionally make the program exit. Then it will restart but I don't know if the timer is resetted. (Probably not.)

Comment: No, this isn't possible. Why does it matter? I suspect you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Comment: @Chris I guess I do have an XY problem. This is my [original issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61593968/how-to-pull-changes-to-sqlite-database-file-for-flask-web-app-from-github-reposi)

Comment: @TylerKempton, I'll add a comment to that question and mark your other question as a duplicate of some others where you can learn more about the problem. Please follow the links to those other questions and read the answers given there.